# What is the name of the distribution of unbiased sample variance for a sample from Gaussian distribution?

Tags: distributions, self-study, estimation, variance

Suppose $X_i$'s are iid Gaussian random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

The distribution of $\sum_i (X_i - \bar{X}_i)^2 / (n-1)$ isn't Chi square. What is its distribution called?

In my case, how do you determine the values of the parameters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a scaled chi-square, which is generally called a gamma distribution.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

The new part of the question is answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22230/probability-density-function-pdf-of-normal-sample-variance-s2), including an excellent hint for the derivation of the scaled chi-square result in comments.

Comment: Thank you. In my case, how do you determine the values of the parameters?

Comment: Doesn't really fit in a comment. Please edit your question, and I'll respond to that in my answer. However, that now sounds rather like routine bookwork, so you should probably add the `self-study` tag (and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info))

Comment: Yes, done. @Glen_b

Comment: In answering it, I found the new question had been answered before, so I am now just pointing to where that part is answered.

Comment: In your answer in the link, $S^2 = \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\cdot \frac{\sigma^2}{(n-1)}\sim \text{Gamma}(\frac{(n-1)}{2},\frac{2\sigma^2}{(n-1)})$. Should it be $S^2 = \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\cdot \frac{\sigma^2}{(n-1)}\sim \text{Gamma}(\frac{(n-1)}{2},\frac{2\sigma}{\sqrt{n-1}})$ instead?

Comment: No, it's right as it is. The two arguments are the shape and scale in the [shape-scale parameterization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) of a Gamma. You can see, for example, that the mean of the specified gamma will be  $\frac{(n-1)}{2}\cdot\frac{2\sigma^2}{(n-1)}=\sigma^2$, which you'd expect given that $S^2$ is an unbiased estimator of the variance. (That on its own doesn't show it's correct, of course, but it survives that obvious reasonableness check)